# How to format code syntax in the wordpress blog?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a wordpress blog which i use it for my  personal code references and posted many source code sample syntax. At present code syntax displays same as text display. I am trying to format the code syntax and display the syntax properly.

How to format code syntax  in the wordpress blog (or) do we have plug-ins which support syntax format in the wordpress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this easily with the help of Gutenberg editor. It provides block named code block through which you can add code with proper formatting. If you are using version 5.1 or above then it is provided as built in editor. You can also download Gutenberg plugin.